# SummaryTools dfSummary() not providing output, only HTML

Tags: r, summarytools

Attempting to use SummaryTools on my work PC (Windows). I am trying to run dfSummary() but the only output i get is the HTML code in the console.

I do not have issue using this library on my personal Mac, so i assume this might have something to do with how R is installed but there is no one to help troubleshot this from IT.

Previous related topics have suggest instead of
dfSummary(iris)

to use:

print(dfSummary(iris),method='render')

Neither method works

library(summarytools)
dfSummary(iris)
print(dfSummary(iris),method='render')

Actual output should include pretty graphs and tables. Similar to what is found here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/summarytools/vignettes/Introduction.html

Comment: How about `view(dfSummary(iris))`?  That saves an html file to your computer (I'm on Windows 10) and prints the table to RStudio's viewer (if you're using RStudio).

Comment: OMG Thank you so much Greg!!!!!  This was so simple and worked perfectly

Comment: Note that the `view()` function exists in other packages, so in order to avoid conflicts, you can also use summarytools' `stview()` function which is a shortcut for `summarytools::view()`